# How to use ErrorProvider with ReactiveUI on Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reactiveui, errorprovider

I'm looking for ways to integrate the Windows Forms `ErrorProvider` component into a `ReactiveUI` based application.

The ErrorProvider control relies on Windows Forms' BindingContext/BindingManager infrastructure, which is of course not used by ReactiveUI.

How can I, from the View object's bound Controls, "navigate" back to the properties on the ViewModel to which they are bound? I'm thinking of possibly using .NET attributes on the VM properties, but I'd need some automated way to find which property a control is bound to.

As a different approach, I could create a second property on the VM for each property which needs validation status displayed on the View, and use standard ReactiveUI binding/subscribe mechanism to call `ErrorProvider.SetError()`, but this would have to be manually wired up for each Control, which I'd like to avoid.

So, when iterating Controls on the View, how to "find" which VM property it is bound to, if any.

Comment: `ErrorProvider` relies on `IDataErrorInfo`. Also `DataGridView` which doesn't need `ErrorProvider` to show errors on cells and rows, relies on the same interface. So if you want to use `ErrorProvider` or error feature of `DataGridView`, then you need to implement that interface in your classes. You can see an implementation which allows you to use [DataAnnotations Validation Attributes in Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/). It's not about ReactiveUI, but you will learn how to customize models to use them with `ErrorProvider`.

Comment: @Reza, yes, thanks for pointing out the DataGridView not using the ErrorProvider. After looking into the code for many different .NET classes (using Reflector), I see that the ErrorProvider heavily relies on the classic WinForms DataBinding framework. I'll have to mimic this behavior, but based on ReactiveUI Bindings. I'll rewrite my question differently now that I know what to ask for. Thx.